# Generate commit for oracle SQL file in liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I want to generate a SQL file via liquibase for my oracle database. Is there a possibility to ensure that liquibase generates a `commit;` after every changeset? I thought of manually write after every changeset a commit in `<SQL>` tags but this is actually not a good approach so is there any command for it? I am using liquibase 3.5.5. and generate the SQL file like this:

```
 .\liquibase --url=offline:oracle? 
--changeLogFile="C:\Users\Ferid\Documents\Box Sync\PRIVATE_Ferid\liquibase-3.5.5-bin\cl.xml" 
--outputFile="C:\Users\Ferid\Documents\Box Sync\PRIVATE_Ferid\liquibase-3.5.5-bin\output.sql" 
updatesql
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in general it works without commit after the statements but there can occur some problems when there are many DDL statements and I have a very big SQL file.

Comment: Yeah it does contain many DML statements, sorry I mixed something up.